# Как спарсить нужное значение от json ответа?

Tags: json, swift, парсер

Получаю большой record, но нужно конкретно одно поле. Сам JSON выглядит вот так.
[image: консоль]

Пытаюсь прогнать цикл, чтобы вытащить поле ID. Но не получается.
[image: цикл]

Где у меня ошибка, может я не в том направлении совсем?

Comment: Покажи код, чтобы увидеть ошибку !

Comment: вот код
https://gist.github.com/golub1/cb744b96cb9cbb79ba08fff1eb181f83